# issue with imagecreatfromstring

Tags: php, string

i have a problem with `imagecreatfromstring` in php it getting error like

> Warning: `imagecreatefromstring()`: Data is not in a recognized format in /home/ul2in1x1/public_html/ku.php on line 227
>
> Warning: imagecopy() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/ul2in1x1/public_html/ku.php on line 229

again and again

here is my codes and $ data

```
function getans($data,$cques)
{
    $cque=$cques;
    
    $data = '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';

    $data = base64_decode($data);

    $width=312;
    $height=40;
    $offset_x = 276;
    $offset_y = 0;
    $new_height = 40;
    $new_width = 36;
    
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($data);
    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    imagecopy($new_image, $image, 0, 0, $offset_x, $offset_y, $width, $height);
    imagefilter($new_image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
```

now telll me how to slove the error
Thanks in advance

Comment: The error message is quite clear. We have no idea what your data actually contains – but you should have …

Comment: then tell me my function coding is right?????

Comment: That you’ll find out after you made the current error go away.

Comment: Just a guess from a random guy: As I analyze it, the errors are in `$data` and `$image`. Have a look for what this function does and what they **return** `base64_decode()` and `imagecreatefromstring()`. Hope you'll find it your own.